# Как найти индекс нескольких элементов в массиве,а за тем их прибавить?

Tags: python

Надо найти L минимальных элементов , затем их индекси прибавить.

```
import random
B=[]
S=0
L=int(input())
for n in range(45):
    x = random.randint(0,45)-9
    B.append(x)
    for i in (B):
        for index in range(len(B)):
            if (i>=0):      # надо как то по другому 
                S+=i.index  # это не правильно 


print ("Masiv B:")
print(B)
print ("Min element=",i)
print( "S=",S)
```

Comment: В чем собственно вопрос? И код у Вас какой-то обрезанный.

Comment: Вопрос мой в заголовке "Как найти индекс нескольких элементов в массиве,а за тем их прибавить?
"

Answer (score 0):

```
m = min(B)
sum([i for i, v in enumerate(B) if v == m])
```